# Best way to pass information across pages

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, local-storage

I'm developing a webapplication with Spring MVC, Jquery, JSP. Layout of my application is as below
[image: Index Page]

Here I've choose my preference(eg. home, education and there are many more). So the issue is that, when I navigate to Page 2, it should retain all the preferences selected in Page1.

I really need a page reload for Page 2, so that I can't use Ajax calls.

[image: Page 2]

All these information are passed to the controller from page 1 form submit.  My question is that what is the best way to pass information across pages, basically from controller to page.

The only way is to set through Model And View object from Controller ? Also I do have 6 more, these kind of checkbox divs. So I need to populate all of them which are selected in Page1 to Page2.

Which is the best way with high performance.
Please share thoughts.

[Edit]
Added buttons to explain the use case.

Usecase#1

1. User selects the preference in check boxes
2. The press Application#1 button
3. Form post with selected preferences as params
4. Then valid results are displayed in a text pane for Application#1

Usecase#2
1. If user is not satisfied with Application#1 results, then he has a chance to opt application#2 with selected preferences.

Since Application#1 submission is form post with entire page reload, the user preferences are not more retained. I want to retain these information.

I know, it can be set through ModelAndView object, but need to know the best way in terms of performance and any other options.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't get an idea of what you are doing.but a I hope it will useful
in my view 
    you want to send some data (user selected) to page2.
To send the data to the server you can use Ajax,
    but good way is using "form" (it will load new page)

and it's simple to use.

Comment: Abilash, I added use case for better understanding of the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The main step of the solution is to have a server side model (or form bean) object to hold the user selection of preference, as you already mentioned. The solution also depends on the scope of the preference data which you can decide and handle. Have ajax call to update the model on change of selection in the preference form. Based on the scope of the preference data the model object is available to other components. So when you click Application#1 or Application#2 you call controller, retrieve the preference object from the used scope (session or custom) in it and the request-response will be normal page load based. As the preference is saved through ajax so it doesn't need to be submitted on every link click. If you maintain this object based on true scope needed you wont create any overhead on server as well.

Comment: I liked the idea of maintaining a session scoped object. I'll try and let you know the status.

Answer (score 0):

yes i got your idea (not sure 50%)...
 if we used "form" then it can be used once...
but you need to store it.....
is it right...
    using form you can do this

page2 will get "data" via "form post" from page1
then you must save data in server(database)..or using "php"  write "data" in the form of js or html
inside the page2..

but idont know is it possible to "tick the selection box" (users selected)

using php is more good (speed,) i think

iam not experianced but.i give sometime to you. it may usefull..

Comment: Yes, I want to "save the user preferences(checked)" in page 2